# Volume defined in docker-compose not mounting

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
web:
    build: web
    volumes:
    - .:/data
```

And `web/Dockerfile` is like this:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN start_some_service.sh
```

But that `data` volume isn't being mounted. `docker inspect` says so:

```
"Volumes": null
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

---

Also tried:

```
volumes:
- ".:/app"
```

But the problem persists.

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml config` shows the following:

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: /Users/zoran/code/test/web
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
    - /Users/zoran/code/test:/app:rw
version: '2.1'
```

Comment: try to add 2 whitespaces before `- ".:/app"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is necessary to specify both `build` and `image` options for the volumes to be mounted:

```
web:
    build: web
    image: my-web-image
    volumes:
      - .:/data
```